# Http/observables now not working after angular 2 modules update

Tags: angular, http, observable

The Http calls worked before I reinstalled/update the angular modules to the latest. Now i've discovered all Http calls/observables now return an error of NOT FOUND (http://localhost:4200/data/notifications.json 404 [Not Found]). Please can you let me know what needs updating, have I forgotten something? Here is my code:

NotificationService.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

    constructor(private _http: Http){}

    GetAllNotifications(queryUrl: string){
       return this._http.get(queryUrl).map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

}
```

NotificationComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Notification, NotificationType } from './notification.entity';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'e-notifications',
    templateUrl: './templates/notification.template.html'
})

export class NotificationComponent implements INotificationComponent {
    notifType = NotificationType;
    public notificationsCollection: Notification[];
    private queryUrl = "../../../data/notifications.json";
    notifSub: any;

    constructor(private _notificationService: NotificationService) { 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.notifSub = this._notificationService.GetAllNotifications(this.queryUrl)
       .subscribe((response) => this.notificationsCollection = response);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.notifSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Dev dependencies:

```
 "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.1",
```

Comment: Why are you making Http requests to get data that's already in your application?

Comment: The RestfulAPI I will be fetching from is not ready yet...

Comment: Then I'd suggest using `MockBackend` to do this, as shown in e.g. https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-mockbackend/, http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/11/24/angular-2-mockbackend-example-for-backendless-development. That way you can move the fake URLs out of your services and have less to change when the API does exist.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks for your answer... just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't define providers in the module, add providers in NotificationComponent.ts

Also import Observable and HTTP_PROVIDERS

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import { Notification, NotificationType } from './notification.entity';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'e-notifications',
    templateUrl: './templates/notification.template.html',
    providers : [HTTP_PROVIDERS, NotificationService]
})

export class NotificationComponent implements INotificationComponent {
    notifType = NotificationType;
    public notificationsCollection: Notification[];
    private queryUrl = "../../../data/notifications.json";
    notifSub: any;

    constructor(private _notificationService: NotificationService) { 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.notifSub = this._notificationService.GetAllNotifications(this.queryUrl)
       .subscribe((response) => this.notificationsCollection = response);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.notifSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```